# Error probability of repetition code

Tags: probability, coding-theory

I am very lost. I would like to know how I calculate the probability of finding errors in repetition code.

For example say the codewords are 111 or 000 and probability of an error is 0.1. How would I find the probability of having one error in the transmitted codeword? i.e the chance that 000 becomes 001, 010, 100 or 111 becomes 110, 101, 011?

Am I correct to believe that this formula is the answer? 
Where P is the probability 0.1

$$3p^{2}(1 − p) + p^{3} = 0.028$$

If so, how would I compute the chance of receiving a codeword with one error with a repetition code of (4,1) or (5,1), (6,1) etc. I cannot find any examples that make this clear or if I'm even on the right tracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct to believe that this formula is the answer?

What you need is not to know "the formula", but where it comes from.

In $(3,1)$ repetition code, we code the `0` as `000`. The decoding (assuming a BSC channel with crossover (bit error) probability $p<1/2$) is by majority: if, say, we receive `001` we decide that it's more probable that the trasmitted codeword was `000` than `111`.  Why? Because it's more probable to have a single bit error (`000`  $\to$ `001` : last bit was changed) than having two (`111`  $\to$ `001` : two first bit changed).

When does this decoding strategy fail? It should be clear that the decoding is wrong where there are indeed two bit-errors ... or three.  If we trasmit `000` and the first and last bit are flipped, so we receive `101`, the decode will guess : `111` and we'll have  decoding error. Conclusion: the event "decoding error" is equivalent to the event "having more than half bit errors". The formula you copied computes this, the first term correspond to the 2-bits errors (there are 3 possible cases) and the last term for the 3-bits error.

If you understood the above, then you should be able to compute the probability of bad decoding for a repetition $(5,1)$ code (I've never seen a $(4,1)$ repetition code ; even lengths are avoided to get rid of ties).

Comment: I do believe that I can make sense of that, thank you. I understood the formula but you are right, I needed to know where it comes from so I could work with different repetition codes. I could not find any examples that explained this as clearly as you have.